How can I find the source code used for a function in the latest QGIS Field calculator?
I am having difficulty understanding how QGIS calculates the difference between two dates with the "AGE" function and would like to see how it is coded.
If this is possible, how do I find the source?

It is available here. We see it is computed as the number of seconds between the two inputs.
static QVariant fcnAge( const QVariantList &values, const QgsExpressionContext *, QgsExpression *parent, const QgsExpressionNodeFunction * )
{
  QDateTime d1 = QgsExpressionUtils::getDateTimeValue( values.at( 0 ), parent );
  QDateTime d2 = QgsExpressionUtils::getDateTimeValue( values.at( 1 ), parent );
  qint64 seconds = d2.secsTo( d1 );
  return QVariant::fromValue( QgsInterval( seconds ) );
}

